# Favorite tags/filters on Android App

Tags: feature-request, tags, android-app

I login to my SO mobile android app to browse for questions/answers for very specific tags every time. I wish there was an easy way to do that in one click: like a favorite tags or a recent tags menu/button somewhere on the home screen or feeds page. Right now I have to either search for tags myself or open a similar question, click on the tag to go to tag filter view and then retype the filter. I wish this 2 or 3 step process is reduced to a one click menu/option on the home page/menu.

Thank you guys. Again, the app is wonderful.

Comment: @guessimtoolate that question you linked to us for the website. The one I have asked is for the Android app. So this is _NOT_ a duplicate of that.

Comment: Yeah my bad, sorry. I'd love to have that feature on both versions. If there's a way to "unflag" the question then I would.

Comment: @guessimtoolate no way to cancel flag and only one close vote, it will expire soon so no big deal.

Comment: Found a "real" dupe though. :)

Comment: Oh Ok awesome. I don't mind having the question closed, as long as the feature request went though somewhere.